# Python function (lettuce step) always retrurn True

Tags: python, selenium, lettuce

I am working with selenium and lettuce for testing in python.
I have this step for counting employee table rows

```
@step('I count employee table rows')
def i_count_emp_table_rows(step):
    try:
        elems = world.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='myTable']/tr")
        sum = 0
        for item in elems:
            sum= sum+1
        return sum
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return None
```

And I have another step, In this step, I want to save the number of employees in employee table (using above step) before I go to next page after clicking Add Employee Button.

```
@step('I click the Add Employee Button')
def i_click_the_add_employee_button(step):
    world.prev_no_of_emp = step.given('I count employee table rows')
    print "Right Now total rows in table: " + str(world.pre_no_of_emp)
    done, world.driver = click_page_element(admin_add_employee_button_xpath, world.driver, wait=10)
```

But the funny thing is that I always get "True" instead of a list count. I even used ***len()*** but no success
Here is the result of print statement.

 
**Right Now total rows in table: True**

Comment: `step.given`  is returning `True`. You mind showing `step.given`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yes I already did. The above function is being called here.

Comment: @AdilMalik calling step that way returns True if the step is successfully executed. That means return statement is useless in this case.

Comment: @AdilMalik if you want to get the count, you need to put that into 'world' variable or in any other global variable.

Comment: @HassanMehmood I did, Infact i am using **world.pre_no_of_emp** in print statement

Comment: @HassanMehmood Ok i got it. Thanks. You are right

Comment: @AdilMalik I have updated your steps, See below answer. And you'r welcome :)

Comment: @HassanMehmood There is issue with your answer. I want this step to be generic. So whenever i need to check the row count of employee table, I call that step.   But the way you suggested will become limited. But yes if there is no returning So i need to do some hacks.

Comment: Well you can do that, whats the issue ?.. Also I think what you want is can be done by simple function. There is no need to create a separate step for that. Create a simple method which returns you number of rows.

Comment: Solved :). Yes I know this can be done with simple function. Issue Resolved

Comment: Using global variable, the way you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the count into some global variable. See below updated steps.

```
@step('I count employee table rows')
def i_count_emp_table_rows(step):
    try:
        elems = world.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='myTable']/tr")
        world.count = len(elems)
    except Exception, e:
        print e.message
        world.count = None

@step('I click the Add Employee Button')
def i_click_the_add_employee_button(step):
    step.given('I count employee table rows')
    print "Right Now total rows in table: " + str(world.count)
    done, world.driver = click_page_element(admin_add_employee_button_xpath, world.driver, wait=10)
```